# Repeated Measures ANOVA with blocking factor using nlme

Tags: r, anova, mixed-models, nlme, emmeans

I would like to make sure this is correct even though I think it is similar to other versions on stackoverflow but not exactly the same.

**Exp Design:**

- Blocks - north fields and south fields
- Treatments - reference, treat_1, treat_2
- Time as months - 3, 4, 5, 6
- Response variable is nitrate - no3

The north fields have two replicates and the south fields have 1 replicate. The replicates are 2 acre fields where we measured nitrate over time in the soil as it responded to the treatments.

Packages are:

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(car)
library(multcompView)
library(nlme)
library(emmeans)
```

Below is a simplified data frame.

```
no3.df <- structure(list(month = c(3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 3, 3, 3, 
                4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 3, 3, 
                3, 4, 6, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 3, 3, 3, 
                4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6), 
                block = c("north", "north", "north", "north", "north", "north", "north", "north", 
                        "north", "north", "north", "north", "north", "north", "north", 
                        "north", "north", "north", "south", "south", "south", "south", 
                        "south", "south", "south", "north", "north", "north", "north", 
                        "north", "north", "north", "north", "north", "north", "north", 
                        "south", "south", "south", "south", "south", "south", "south", 
                        "north", "north", "north", "north", "north", "north", "north", 
                        "north", "north", "north", "north", "north", "north", "north", 
                        "north", "north", "north", "south", "south", "south", "south", 
                        "south", "south", "south", "south", "south"), 
                plot = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
                        8, 8, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 
                        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
                        7, 7, 7, 7), 
                treatment = c("treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", 
                       "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", 
                       "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", 
                       "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", 
                       "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_2", "treat_2", "treat_2", 
                       "treat_2", "treat_2", "treat_2", "treat_2", "treat_2", "treat_2", 
                       "treat_2", "treat_2", "treat_2", "treat_2", "treat_2", "treat_2", 
                       "treat_2", "treat_2", "treat_2", "reference", "reference", "reference", 
                       "reference", "reference", "reference", "reference", "reference", 
                       "reference", "reference", "reference", "reference", "reference", 
                       "reference", "reference", "reference", "reference", "reference", 
                       "reference", "reference", "reference", "reference", "reference", 
                       "reference", "reference", "reference"), 
                no3 = c(36.8, 20.4925, 21.03333333, 16.33, 7.723, 1.566333333, 0.533333333, 0.189, 0.31, 
                     25.8, 16.13333333, 24.86666667, 3.979, 1.814, 0.34635, 0.244666667, 
                     0.247333333, 0.97675, 14.305, 11.91, 12.4, 6.79, 7.26825, 8.4615, 
                     3.43575, 22.225, 0.3243, 0.1376, 0.6244, 0.962233333, 1.36675, 
                     8.27, 14.96, 19.62, 44.7, 9.197, 15.6, 13.85, 17.76, 14.84, 17.8, 
                     23.06, 12.19333333, 19.06, 22.675, 27.47, 18.295, 16.5425, 18.7375, 
                     22.25333333, 24.63125, 21.75, 23.73333333, 13.09, 20.54, 17.1, 
                     10.58666667, 17.5565, 20.5, 25.575, 19.8, 15.76666667, 18.25333333, 
                     15.93, 11.89, 10.791, 22.65, 22.025, 23.93333333)), 
           row.names = c(NA, -69L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Read in the data and made factors

```
no3.df <- no3.df %>% 
  mutate( 
         treatment = as.factor(treatment),
         plot=as.factor(plot),
         month=as.factor(month))
```

I am using **nlme** to specify the covariance/variance structure. Eventually I will try this with other covariance and variance structures and look at AIC to see what is best but for now the approach I think might work best as a AR1 matrix.

```
lme_fitno3.block <- lme(fixed =no3 ~ treatment * month ,  
                    random = ~1|plot/block, 
                    method='REML',
                    corr = corAR1( form= ~1|plot/block),
                    data = no3.df)
summary(lme_fitno3.block)
Anova(lme_fitno3.block, type="III")
```

The model results are"

```
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III tests)

Response: no3
                  Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
(Intercept)     50.8817  1  9.810e-13 ***
treatment        1.9561  2      0.376    
month            3.4219  3      0.331    
treatment:month 29.7859  6  4.317e-05 ***
```

I take from this that there is a significant interaction of treatment and month and then do followup tests.

```
marginal = emmeans(lme_fitno3.block, 
                   ~ treatment:month)

plot(marginal, comparisons = TRUE)

emminteraction = emmeans(lme_fitno3.block, 
                         pairwise ~ treatment:month,
                         adjust="bonferroni",
                         alpha=0.5)
emminteraction$contrasts
multcomp::cld(marginal,
              Letters = letters,
              adjust="bonferroni")
```

I won't post the results as they are extensive.

Comment: If you question is "how to modify the code below to get: random slopes, random intercepts" then you can reduce your post's length and complexity considerably and strip down to the bare essentials necessary to show what you've tried and why it's failing. If you want a confirmation of your statistical interpretation then [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) is a better place to post. Finally, requests for book recommendations or other resources are generally not considered valid topics for SO posts, and may be removed - I would suggest removing that bit from your post as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that might have been interested I did find a good introduction and example R code for nlme and lme4 at [website for repeated measures and random factors](https://www.flutterbys.com.au/stats/tut/tut9.3a.html#mjx-eqn-tabrandomizedBlockAnova-correlationStructures)